# How to get Century from date in Java

Tags: java, date

How to get current Century from a date in Java?

For example the date `"06/03/2011"` according to format `"MM/dd/yyyy"`. How can I get current century from this date using `SimpleDateFormat`?

Comment: What do you want as century in this case, "19"?

Comment: I want to get current century

Comment: 2011 is in the 21st century. Do you want exactly this value?

Comment: yes I want exactly the value '21'

Comment: Expect it to be partially depending on culture. The *Dansk sprognævn* (Danish Language Council) once decided that the new *århundrede*, century, started Jan 1, 2000 (not 2001). I disagree, but I do expect users in some places to prefer talking about *the 1900s* (maybe no good English term exists) over *the 20th century*.

Answer (score 15):

A slight change to what Harry Lime posted. His logic is not entirely correct. Year 1901 would be 20th century, but 1900 would be 19th century.

```
public class CenturyYear {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int test = centuryFromYear(1900);
        System.out.println(test);

    }

    static int centuryFromYear(int year) {
        if (year % 100 == 0) {
            year = year / 100;
        } else {
            year = (year / 100) + 1;
        }
        return year;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 14):

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(yourString);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date);

int century = (calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) / 100) +1;
```

Comment: If you consider 1 AD to 100 AD to be the first hundred years you need `(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) + 99 / 100)` but if you consider the 20th century to be 1900 to 1999, the formula is correct.

Comment: Yes, that is indeed what we need to do: the stupid `+1`... I hate it. Why do only programmers know it is much more interesting to start counting from zero? Year 0-99 should be century 0. 2000-2099 should be century 20. Can it be more logic then this?

Answer (score 6):

The other Answers are correct but outdated.

## java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

Now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project also advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time.

## `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

To parse specify a formatting pattern. By the way, I suggest using ISO 8601 standard formats which can be parsed directly by java.time classes.

```
String input = "06/03/2011";

DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "MM/dd/uuuu" ).withLocale ( Locale.US );
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse ( input , f );
```

To get the century, just take the year number and divide by 100. If you want the [ordinal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number), "twenty-first century" for 20xx, add one.

```
int centuryPart = ( ld.getYear () / 100 );
int centuryOrdinal = ( ( ld.getYear () / 100 ) + 1 );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "input: " + input + " | ld: " + ld + " | centuryPart: " + centuryPart + " | centuryOrdinal: " + centuryOrdinal );
```

> input: 06/03/2011 | ld: 2011-06-03 | centuryPart: 20 | centuryOrdinal: 21

Answer (score 3):

```
int century =  (year + 99)/ 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know anything about Java but why don't you just get the full year and make the last 2 digits 0?

**EDIT**

If you want 2011 to become 21st century - just get the fully qualified year in string format, then knock off the last 2 characters, then parse to an int and add 1!

Comment: Likely because that doesn't meet his requirements.

Comment: yes but he doesn't say what his requirements are, and doing what I suggesst would give him the century...

Comment: If we go with a conventional definition of the centuries, your formula would give a wrong result for the last year of every century. For example, it would state that year 2000 belonged to the 21st century.

Answer (score 0):

You would simply return (year + 99) / 100

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. This is exactly what [the answer by Chinthaka Devinda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70213767/5772882) already said. I don’t see anything useful in repeating it here.

Comment: Was already commented before

Answer (score -2):

Split it by the slahes, get the first two symbols of the third element in the resulting array, Integer.parseInt it and add 1, that is: 

`String arr = myDate.split("/");
String shortYear = myDate[2].substring(0, 2);
int century = Integer.parseInt(shortYear) + 1;`

(not sure about the substring() syntax off the top of my head)