# java method int getCentury()

Tags: java

In my homework I have to make java method int getCentury().This method must print century by input year,date and month.For example the date insert from user is 1878 03 03 and print 1878 03 03 – 19 century.

```
int getCentury() { 

    int century = 21; 

    System.out.println(century); 

    if (year % 100 == 0) { 
        year = year / 100; 
    } else { 
        year = (year / 100) + 1; 
    } 

    return century; 
}
```

Comment: int getCentury() {
    int century = 21;
    System.out.println(century);
      if (year % 100 == 0) {
               year = year / 100;
           } else {
               year = (year / 100) + 1;
           }
           return century;
       }

Comment: hint: in your code, where do you change the value of `century`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Century from date in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229347/how-to-get-century-from-date-in-java)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please explain more precisely what you are having trouble with (assuming that you are having trouble with something since you wanted to post a question).

Answer (score 1):

Many answers, many alternative ways, none pointing at the actual issue in your code...

Your method creates a variable `century`, initializes it, does unrelated thing and returns it.

You never change the value of `century`after its initialization. Instead you change the value of `year`.

```
year = (year / 100) + 1;  // that doesn't change the variable century
```

Simply assign the result of your calculation to `century`and it should works. (and `year` won't be modified!)

```
int getCentury() { 

    int century; // No need to initialize this.

    // remove the print, or put it right before the return to get the result and not the initialization value

    if (year % 100 == 0) { 
        century = year / 100; 
    } else { 
        century = (year / 100) + 1; 
    } 

    return century; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a following way to do this. 
Split your text by the first space i.e. 
`String[] arrOfStr = str.split(" ", 2);` In the first half of array, you'll get:
`arrOfStr[0] = 1878`.
Parse this value to integer. Then use following code to get first two digits of year:
`int firsttwodigits = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(year.substring(0, 2));
//In this way, you will have firsttwodigits = 18`

```
public int getCentury(String date) {
   String[] arrOfStr = date.split(" ", 2);
   int year = Integer.parseInt(arrOfStr[0]);
   int firsttwodigits = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(year.substring(0, 2));

   return firsttwodigits;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the following code?

```
    private int getCentury(GregorianCalendar calendar) {
        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        int century = year / 100;
        if(year % 100 != 0) {
            century += 1;
        }

        return century;
    }
```

You can change the param as GregorianCalendar object before you sent it.

```
    GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    calendar.set(1878, 03, 03);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use the new Java Time API.

```
String date = "2000 01 01";

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu MM dd");
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(date, formatter);
```

You can then rewrite your original method as:

```
public static int getCentury(LocalDate date) {
    int year = date.getYear();
    if (year % 100 == 0) {
        return year / 100;
    } else {
        return  (year / 100) + 1;
    }
}
```

If neccessary, you can add exception handling to `LocalDate#parse`.